# Unauth Firebase user using new Firebase SDK

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the old Firebase we could simply unauth/log out a user by using:

```
reference.unauth()
```

I'm not seeing anywhere, even in their docs, how to do it in the new Firebase. Perhaps I am missing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
```

Reference to documents: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) at the bottom.

Note for editor:
try! is written when you know function that can throw will succeed. So its a part of statement. Thanks for the edit though.

Comment: try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut() does not completely sign out the user. After the previous method is run, I run print(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser.uid), and the user id is still printed out. Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I perform my sign out, and it seems to work for me. Hope this helps.

```
    do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }
```